# Writing a delegate as a Func

Tags: c#, delegates, lambda

this works:

```
    //delegate
    Parallel.For(1023456789, 1033456789, delegate(long i)
            {
                if (i % 10000000 == 0) Console.WriteLine("{0:N0}", i);
                if (IsPanDigital(i))
                {
                    list.Add(i);
                }
            }
        );

    //lambda expression
    Parallel.For(1023456789, 1033456789, i =>
            {
                if (i%10000000 == 0) Console.WriteLine("{0:N0}", i);
                if (IsPanDigital(i))
                {
                    list.Add(i);
                }
            }
        );
```

Is it possible to rewrite this logic using a Func?  I've tried here..doesn't compile.

```
    var list = new List<long>();
    Parallel.For(1023456789, 1033456789, Blah(i, ref list));

public static Func<long> Blah(long i, ref List<long> list)
{
    if (i % 10000000 == 0) Console.WriteLine("{0:N0}", i);
    if (IsPanDigital(i))
    {
        list.Add(i);
    }
}
```

Am trying to see if it can be done.

Comment: What compilation error did you get?

Comment: Note that adding to a list from multiple threads in parallel is not thread-safe.

Comment: Why is your `list` parameter pass-by-reference? You don't change its value anywhere...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You nearly had it:

```
public static void Blah(long i, ref List<long> list)
{
    if (i % 10000000 == 0) Console.WriteLine("{0:N0}", i);
    if (IsPanDigital(i))
    {
        list.Add(i);
    }
}

var list = new List<long>();
Parallel.For(1023456789, 1033456789, i => Blah(i, ref list));
```

(I changed `Blah`'s return type to `void`, and add `i =>` to wrap it in a lambda so it can match `Action<long>`)

Edit: Or change `Blah` to `Action<long>` and do some other minor refactoring:

```
public static Action<long> Blah(List<long> list)
{
    return i =>
    {
        if (i % 10000000 == 0) Console.WriteLine("{0:N0}", i);
        if (IsPanDigital(i))
        {
            list.Add(i);
        }
    };
}

var list = new List<long>();
Parallel.For(1023456789, 1033456789, Blah(list));
```

I think this second example is closer to what you were trying to achieve.

As @lee pointed out, the `ref` parameter, at least in the code you've shown, is not needed.  `ref` parameters also can't be used inside lambdas, which caused a compiler error, so I removed it.  If you really need to use `ref`, go for the first example.

The reason you can't use `Func` is because a `Func<T>` is something that returns a `T` value, and `Parallel` is looking for an `Action<T>`, which returns void.

@dtb pointed out something very important: "Note that adding to a list from multiple threads in parallel is not thread-safe." You might be able to fix this by putting a lock around your `list.Add` method, locking to a `private static object`.  I would guess the vast majority of your work is in calculating `IsPanDigital`, so I think this makes sense.

Comment: You don't need the `ref` modifier for the `list` argument.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who answered / commented - great to have working code.  Passing by ref.. yep.. didn't need that at all.  For now I'm going to stick with the delegate syntax as I like its clarity.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know what you want to do with it, but your function hat to be

- static
- void name(int i)

here is some code that compiles

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

        static List<long> list = new List<long>();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            //delegate
            Parallel.For(1023456789, 1033456789, delegate(long i)
            {
                if (i % 10000000 == 0) Console.WriteLine("{0:N0}", i);
                if (IsPanDigital(i))
                {
                    list.Add(i);
                }
            });

            //lambda expression
            Parallel.For(1023456789, 1033456789, i =>
            {
                if (i % 10000000 == 0) Console.WriteLine("{0:N0}", i);
                if (IsPanDigital(i))
                {
                    list.Add(i);
                }
            });

            Parallel.For(1023456789, 1033456789, Blah); //other overloads do accept other Actions

        }

        private static bool IsPanDigital(long i)
        {
            return false;
        }

        public static void Blah(int i) // = Action<int i>
        {
            if (i % 10000000 == 0) Console.WriteLine("{0:N0}", i);
            if (IsPanDigital(i))
            {
                list.Add(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```